# jQuery tabs (click on tab and link redirect)

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, tabs

I have jQuery tabs

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">First</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Third</a></li>
                <li class="last" ><a href="/More.aspx" >Learn more...</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>

    <script>
         $("#tabs").tabs({
             fx: [{ opacity: 'toggle', duration: 'normal' }, 
{ opacity: 'toggle', duration: 'fast'}]
         }).addClass('ui-tabs-vertical');

         $("li.last a").unbind('click').each(function () {
             this.href = $.data(this, 'href.tabs');
         });
    </script>
```

that work in jquery 1.7.2 but not in 2.1.0...

I need option to click on tab in this situation last redirect  on some link just like ordinary link... I get:

> /undefined and need redirect to More.aspx

Comment: This is an awful question....You will not get help without clarification.

Comment: I add more info! Is now better?
Thanks for suggestion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mabe this is what you lookin for http://jsfiddle.net/sickworm/w4xcth1c/

```
 $(function () {

        $("#tabs").tabs();
        $("li.last a").unbind('click');


    });
```